# How to eliminate the jQuery tooltip fade effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery ui tooltip function and I feel like the fade in tooltip is a little annoying.

I had added delay : 0 but its still does the  fading.

Does anyone have a solution to this or can recommend another tooltip functionality? Thanks!

Below is my code

```
$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip({
        show: {
            effect:'toggle',
            delay:0

        },
        content: function () {
            return $(this).prop("title");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use:

```
show: false
```

This disables the effect on show event. Same goes for `hide`.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/kyBwU/4348/)**

Source: http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-show

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use `show:false` because you need to set other show properties, for example, you really do want a delay before the tooltip displays, but just want the tooltip to appear after the delay with no animation effect, you can use `effect: "none"` as shown below:

```
show: {
    delay: 500,
    effect: "none"
}
```